# How to say this Ajax call in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am struggling with this Ajax call from Rails 2:

```
   def add_task_link(name)
      link_to_function name do |page|
         page.insert_html :bottom, :tasks, :partial => 'task', :object => Task.new
      end
   end
```

How can I express this with Rails 3?

Thanks,

Comment: I have tried this:   link_to_function name, "task" do |page|
But this gives some JS code in an "onclick" attribute that I don't understand what to do with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some hints in this project in Github: https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples

```
   def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
     new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
     fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
         render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
      end
      link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
    end
```

Additionally, it is important to use  accepts_nested_attributes_for as shown in

https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/blob/master/app/models/survey.rb

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want link_to :remote => true instead. The link_to_function is meant to accept a string of javascript code that it puts in the onclick attribute. So instead of your helper method, use something like

```
<%= link_to 'My Link', new_task_path, :remote => true %>
```

Then in your new action, you need to add a .js respond to block.

```
def new
  @task = Task.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render :layout => false } # add this line
  end
end
```

Then create a file under app/views/tasks called `new.js.erb`, and add:

```
$('body').append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "form", :locals => { :task => @task }) %>');
```

Provided the partial form is setup (which you can use anyways for your new.html.erb and edit.html.erb files) that should work just fine. Took some examples from this example repository: https://github.com/nu7hatch/rails3-ujs-example/blob/master/ I have to admit, I don't do a lot of link_to remote coding examples in Rails. Most ajax calls I do are using JSON responses. So I write the js code under the asset pipeline.

Comment: that is a nice summary for loading a normal snippet of HTML . The situation I am an in uses a input fields that must be "synched" with the rest of a form. I still have to learn a bit more on Ajax to fully understand the solution below. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: If i read that correctly, you wish to add additional fields to the form on the fly? Then you can still use the above code, just adjust it. Instead of appending to the body, append to your form tag. Create another partial containing the fields you need. then simply reference that partial name in the new.js.erb file.